# When background image hidden, no border in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When i set the visibility of the background images to hidden the border inside the table disappears.
How do i keep the borders inside ? I add the picture in when the site is loaded with js and jquery

Here is some my html and css:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1px" id="container" >
  <tr>
    <td class="a"></td>
    <td class="a"></td>
    <td class="a"></td>
    <td class="a"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="a"></td>
    <td class="a"></td>
    <td class="a"></td>
    <td class="a"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="a"></td>
    <td class="a"></td>
    <td class="a"></td>
    <td class="a"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="a"></td>
    <td class="a"></td>
    <td class="a"></td>
    <td class="a"></td>
  </tr>

 </table>
 </body>
 </html>

 .a{
 height:200px;
 width:200px;
  }

 .pic{
 background-image:url(pic.jpg);
 background-size:195px 195px;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 visibiility:hidden;
 }
```

Comment: If you are simply adding the `.pic` class to the `td` element, then you should set `background: Transparent` instead of setting `visibility: hidden`.

Comment: @JocePedno – You should put that in an answer so the user can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply adding the `.pic` class to the `td` element, then you should set `background: Transparent` instead of setting `visibility: hidden`.